# iscsi target to a folder of a mounted parition?

Tags: debian, networking, filesystems

i'm thinking about installing and setting up iscsitarget on my Debian squeeze box. so far, the examples i saw on various Google searches and the debian wiki: http://wiki.debian.org/SAN/iSCSI/iscsitarget

set the path to unmounted devices like `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda`. is it possible to set the path to a folder on a mounted filesystem instead? like: `/home/iscsi_target`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  iSCSI exports a whole disk over the network for another machine to access directly, using its own filesystem drivers.  A directory is not a disk.

If you want to share files and directories, then you need to use a network filesystem, like NFS or CIFS/Samba.

Comment: thanks after doing further research, it came clear to me that iscsi is not capable of directory read/write. i'll stick to my smb and ftp shares

Comment: I disagree. I just created a testbed vm and specified a separate partition for /home. I then looked at the resultant fstab and sure enough, a separate mount point after / for /home. It was pointing to a unique partition.  How is that any different than uuid=nnnnn /home ext4, _netdev 0 0. ?

Comment: @WaltCorey, did you post that comment in the wrong place by mistake?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with this answer or the question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically things that ask for a device node like `/dev/sda1` are looking to read/write a block device instead of a file node. A directory in a mounted filesystem is an entirely different kind of object than a block device node.

Sometimes things that would normally operate on a device can operate on a file. For example various file formats like iso and dmg are basically "images" of block devices saved in a file on some host file system that can have their own file system structures inside them. Some software knows how to deal with these kind of "files".

There do seem to be some notes about fileio vs blockio in on the site you link, although it the documentation is far from complete. That might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I have two NetGear ReadyNAS systems. Both support ISCSI Targets. First you define a group and, within that group, LUNs. For each LUN you can specify how large. Then, on my Linux system, it could be Windows as well, you define ISCSI and configure it to mount each desired LUN at a specific mount point, such as /media/user/data or, in the case of Thunderbird hold you email repository on a shared target such that the data survives an upgrade / install of a new version of the OS. While psusi is correct, you can mount a target as a directory via fstab, such as

UUID=4e53b99d-1c8a-42f1-87de-1067c21b3a98 /media/walt/tbird      ext4 _netdev 0 0